# Model Likes / Dislikes in SQL

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to implement a behaviour similar to Facebook (okay, most similar to YouTube).

In my table I got various `Products`, each `Product` can be *liked* or *disliked* by a `Customer`. I don't want to let the users rate (let's say between 1 and 5 stars), so a simple like or dislike is enough.

What's the best way of representing that?

---

I've thought about three essential tables (next to `Customers`):

`Products` (Id, Name, ...)

`ProductLikes` (Id, CustomerId, ProductId, CreatedOn)

`ProductDislikes` (Id, CustomerId, ProductId, CreatedOn)

But that would mean to have two tables with nearly the exact same data.

---

Another idea was to have the following:

`Products` (Id, Name, ...)

`ProductLikes` (Id, CustomerId, ProductId, IsLike, CreatedOn)

But that would mean I cannot provide a third state later on, if I decided to do so.

---

And my last idea:

`Products` (Id, Name, ...)

`ProductRatings` (Id, ProductId, CustomerId, Rating, CreatedOn)

Where a "like" would be a Rating of 5.0, a "dislike" one of 1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go for a variant somewhat between your second and third options:

```
Products (Id, Name, ...)

ProductVotes (Id, CustomerId, ProductId, Vote, CreatedOn)
```

The column `Vote` should be constrained to only allow the values `Like` and `Dislike` or, if you prefer, `1` and `-1` -- the latter having the advantage of a simpler possibility to do the `sum()` of the likes and dislikes to get an overall vote.

Comment: Adding a column `Comment` to the `Votes` table (like you said in another answer) is also a good idea. Thank you! I might also add that these votes are cast on a specific ProductVersion rather than the Product itself. And the overall Products likes/dislikes/votes/whatever is the sum of all the versions votes... If that makes sense? ;)

Comment: upvoted! how would vote work if you had something like dislike love and anger

Comment: You could have Dislike, Love, and Anger as allowable values for `vote`. Whether you make this a foreign key or use an Enum type or even an integer depends on how you want to physically model this in your DBMS.